# Using serverless for synchronous RPC microservices

Tags: aws-lambda, microservices, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless

Let's say I have an API Gateway for third parties to create orders in my system. As a part of order creation I need to validate that the request model I have been provided is correct - not just statically but by checking foreign keys are valid - that the product id’s are valid in the order, the account id is valid. If not I want to return a 400 to let the caller know they have passed an erroneous request.

What I would expect to do is to create an orders::createOrder lambda function, which would make parallel calls to products::listProducts, accounts::listAccountsForCustomer and other microservices to retrieve the information needed for validation, before I am happy to create the order in the system. This validation needs to happen synchronously as it’s a request/response from a third party to create the order.

I would usually want the logical domains - customers, products, orders, accounts to be separate microservices, and I usually have some logic in an API Gateway layer for orchestration / mapping to the microservices below. I've been reading that calling Lambda from Lambda is a bad idea..

How do I correctly model this on serverless?

Answer (score 0):

For your case it'll be best to keep all this logic within one lambda. Splitting it into multiple smaller functions will add latency, so you have worse user experience and you'll multiply your cost since you have multiple functions running. You can also try Step Functions if you want such split. But it's also pretty expensive, I don't recommend it for such simple case.